# Unable to Install Gems from Vendor Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler

In spite of the fact Capistrano executes bundle install with the flag `--local` gems from the vendor cache are NOT installed into the shared bundle path. Instead I'm notified that:

> Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
>
> Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources

libv8-3.3.10.4 is definitely located in the vendor/cache. Does anyone know why bundler won't install the gems from the cache?

The full command Capistrano executes is below.

```
"cd /home/ari/apps/air/releases/20120209214139 && bundle install --gemfile /home/ari/apps/air/releases/20120209214139/Gemfile --path /home/ari/apps/air/shared/bundle --deployment --local --quiet --without development test"
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Ran `bundle pack` then `bundle install --deployment` cannot find it in `vendor/cache`

Comment: This seems similar: http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/msg/a82af2cc48784d4b. The OP claims to have resolved by installing Rails and then libv8. Not sure if it will work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

From `bundle help install`:

> ```
> --local
>           Do not attempt to connect to rubygems.org,  instead  using  just
>           the  gems already present in Rubygems' cache or in vendor/cache.
>           Note that if a more appropriate platform-specific gem exists  on
>           rubygems.org, it will not be found.
> ```

Note: `libv8` builds native extensions when it's first installed. This could cause problems if you vendor the gem for one platform and attempt to use it on another.

Either the gems are not present in the Rubygems cache on the server, or the gems are not present in `vendor/cache` in your deployment. So if you see the gem in your `vendor/cache` directory, then it could be that bundler doesn't know where to look for your `vendor/cache` gems.

What's the output of `cd /home/ari/apps/air/releases/20120209214139 && bundle list`? If it's not showing up there, but you can find it on the server, then you know that bundler doesn't know where the `vendor/cache` gems are.

Try doing a `gem env` via your login and compare against `gem env` output via Capistrano. See if the GEM PATHS output differs.